# Cannot set Log Level in custom python Logging class

Tags: python

I have this custom logger class which extends default logging class. The code is simple but I don't understand why I couldn't change log level.

```
class Logger(logging.getLoggerClass()):
    CRITICAL = 50
    FATAL = CRITICAL
    ERROR = 40
    WARNING = 30
    WARN = WARNING
    INFO = 20
    DEBUG = 10
    NOTSET = 0
    def setLevel(self, level):
        super().setLevel(level)
    def error_if(self, condition, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if condition:
            super().error(msg, args, kwargs)
```

User example:

```
import logging

logger = Logger("test_logger")

logger.setLevel(Logger.DEBUG)

logger.info("info1")
logger.debug("debug1")
logger.warning("warn1")
logger.error("error1")
logger.error("error2")
logger.info("info2")
logger.info("info3")
```

Output:

```
warn1
error1
error2
```

Comment: I am not a logging specialist, but what you are trying to do is not quite clear: How are you importing logging (star import)? Why are you masking the logging module `Logger class` name, and seemingly the logging constants, inside your `Logger class`. Then you are asking why you cannot change the logging level, but you are not calling the `setLevel` method"

Comment: You custom logger has no handler.